# Deploying app on domain path using cloudflare tunnel

Tags: dns, domain, tunnel, cloudflare

I have an app running on `port` and want to deploy it on the domain subdirectory, i.e. `example.com/app`. I'd like to use cloudflare tunnel for this, since I already route other apps with it.

I tried setting things up in cloudflare zero trust dashboard > access > tunnels, but when I set up new public hostname, e.g. `example.com/app`, and add a service running on `http://localhost:port` to it, service page is not found on the specified URL. When I delete the path `/app` in the dashboard and let it run on `example.com`, it works fine.

EDIT: I need help with setting the public hostname in the way that the app is accessible on `example.com/app`, what I can't achieve.

I don't want to use subdomain for this, because I have many of them already. I'd like to group certain apps on one subdomain and assign them to different paths.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do or what part you're asking for help with. Consider reading https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry, I hope this edit is correct and the question is now more understandable.

Comment: This is still really vague. Consider posting details about your cloudflare config, your app's config, and including specific error messages that you're getting.